# python csv write error while writing a float value as a column

Tags: python

I want to write the values fetched from url to csv file which has some float values too. The code below shows an error "float found."

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv

url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02'

i=0

csvfile = csv.writer(open('earthquakedet.csv', 'w'))
csvfile.writerow(["Latitude", "Longitude ","Title","Place","Mag"])

json_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
j = json.loads(json_string)

names = [d['properties'] for d in j['features']]
names1 = [d['geometry'] for d in j['features']]

while i <= len(names):

    print names[i]['title']
    print names[i]['place']
    print names[i]['mag']
    print names1[i]['coordinates'][0]
    print names1[i]['coordinates'][1]
    i=i+1
   finalstr=float(names1[i]['coordinates'][0]) + float(names1[i]['coordinates'][1]) + names[i]['title'] + names[i]['place'] + names[i]['mag']

    csvfile.writerow(finalstr)


csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Please reformat your post so the  code able. Also post the full stacktrace, not a paraphrasing of the error.

Comment: `writerow` expects a list representing a row. `csvfile.writerow([finalstr])`. `finalstr` seems to be a misnomer for a float

Comment: hi reformatted now

Comment: i want to write these 5 values obtained as a column in the csv how can do that please help

Answer (score 0):

[`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) takes a list of values to put on the row, not a string. So, instead of concatenating the values yourself, just put them in a list to pass to `writerow`:

```
# ...
i = i + 1

csvfile.writerow([names1[i]['coordinates'][0], names1[i]['coordinates'][1], names[i]['title'], names[i]['place'], names[i]['mag']])
```

Comment: @alagumeenalrajagopal, please accept this answer by clicking the check mark, so that the question will be marked resolved.